# ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python-2.7

```
<code>
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Sedax/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')

    def check(user, password):
        driver.get("https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login")
        user_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("login-username")
        password_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("login-password")
        button_elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-green")

        user_elem.clear()
        password_elem.clear()

        user_elem.send_keys(user)
        password_elem.send_keys(password)
        button_elem.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        driver.get("https://www.spotify.com/us/account/overview/")
        parse = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html5lib')
        for h3 in parse.find_all('h3', {'class': "product-name"}):
            print('{}:{}:{}'.format(user, password, h3.get_text()))

            driver.delete_all_cookies()

            with open('C:/Users/Sedax/Desktop/Accounts.txt') as s:
                for line in s:
                    users, passwords = line.split(':')
                    check(users.strip(), passwords.strip())
</code>
```

Error

> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:50787/devtools/browser/8f806e7d-c77b-4763-af00-6615f6c87d9e
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "funciono.py", line 30, in
>   
>       users, passwords = line.split(':') **ValueError: too many values to unpack**

Comment: Bienvenido Sedax a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 4):

El error que tienes es que estas desempaquetando un conjunto mayor de variables de las que estárías esperando.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
line = "usuario:password:otrodato"
users, passwords = line.split(':')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 2, in
>   
>       users, passwords = line.split(':') ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

El problema es que `line` convertida en una lista con `line.split(':')` tiene más valores de los que estás esperando. Hay varias posibilidades:

#### 1. Desempaquetar todos

```
users, passwords, otrodato = line.split(':')
```

#### 2. Desempaquetar todos pero ignorar los que no se necesitan

```
users, passwords, _ = line.split(':')
```

Podemos usar `_` tantas veces como valores deseamos ignorar

#### 2. Desempaquetar solo los dos valores esperados

```
users, passwords = line.split(':')[:2]
```

Aquí hacemos un recorte (slice) de la lista a solo los dos primeros valores que nos interesa: `line.split(':')[:2]`